# how to solve "TypeError: new_reply() missing 1 required positional argument: 'post_id'"

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to map the specific post id to the reply I am making but when I ran my application it gave me the error

> TypeError: new_reply() missing 1 required positional argument: 'post_id'

when I passed post_id as a static integer 1 and went to the specific post and replied it worked as intended but obviously this is not the solution I'm looking for, any help is appreciated

```
@app.route("/post/reply", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def new_reply(post_id):
    form = ReplyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        reply = Reply(title=form.title.data, content=form.content.data, author=current_user, post_id=post_id)
        db.session.add(reply)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('reply posted', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('Reply.html', title='New Reply', form=form, legend='New Reply')
```

Comment: You can't use `post_id` as function argument because you did not define it in your route like this `@app.route("/post/<post_id>/reply")`

Comment: so if i did ```@app.route("/post/<int:post_id>/reply")``` would that work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add that parameter to your route.

Your current route is:

```
@app.route("/post/reply", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

which provides no `post_id` to your method.

Try

```
@app.route("/post/<int:post_id>/reply", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

which will also convert it into an integer for use by your method.